# Will Australian Computer Society deduct experience if I have internship?

Tags: visa, working-visas, australia, skilled-migration

I have 5 years of experience out of which 2 years was paid internship, 40 hours a week. I worked as a Trainee Associate QA engineer in first year, and as trainee associate software engineer in 2nd year of my internship. Then I have 1.5 years of software engineer experience and am now a QA engineer for the last 6 months. How much will ACS deduct from my application? Any help would be much appreciated as I want to know whether they'll consider my internship and not deduct an years.

Comment: How does "paid internship" differ from "full time employee"?

Comment: Its the same. I was a full time employee but I was still an undergraduate. I was doing my degree part time during the last two years because of the internship

Comment: I think experience doesn't count until you have the degree, UNLESS you have a lot of experience and don't need the degree.

Comment: Does that mean that they'll cut off two years from my experience after degree?

Comment: Next question: How is this a question about expatriates?  Wouldn't exactly the same question apply to a native Australian?

Comment: No because they don't need to do a ACS validation to get a job in Australia. An expat needs this to migrate.

Comment: @mayooran possibly. Find the ACS guidelines.